# conditional expectation; regression

Tags: regression

Assume that

E[$y_{it}|c_i, x_{it}$] = $c_i$ + $x'_{it}\beta$

Eliminate $c_i$ by taking the expectation with respect to $c_i$, leading to

E[$y_{it}|x_{it}$] = E[$c_i|x_{it}$] + $x'_{it}\beta$

Can anybody explain this step?

Comment: Welcome to the site WCB. If this is a homework or self-study question, could you please add the self-study tag?

Comment: Taking the expected value "with respect to $c_i$" or "with respect to $x_i$"? $c_i$ will be "eliminated" (as a random variable), only if we condition it on $x_i$ obtaining a conditional expectation that will be a function of $x_i$.

Answer (score 1):

This works because:

$$ E_{c|x}[E_{y|x,c}[y_{it}|c_{i},x_{it}]|x] = E_{y|x} $$

This is the law of iterated expectations with one more layer of conditioning.

See:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation

Comment: thanks so much.  so we are really taking the expectation with respect to $ $ $c_i$ conditioning on $x_{it}$

Comment: Typically we either always implicitly condition on the data (when it appears in a formula) or treat it as non-random, except when we're explicitly modeling the data, e.g. in a missing data context.